# PowerShell: Find Text between two Words

Tags: regex, apache, tomcat, powershell, between

I need to find out, if there are `maxThreads` and/or `maxConnections` configured in the `connector port 8080` of tomcat.

example:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       maxThreads="600"
       maxConnections="3000"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="443" />
```

I tried it with `regex` but poorly failed.

```
$file = Get-Content "D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\conf\server.xml"
$pattern = "(?<=.*protocol=""HTTP/1.1"")\w+?(?=connectionTimeout=""20000"".*)"
$Opts = [Regex]::Match($file, $pattern)
```

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is straightforward

```
PS>[xml]$x=gc "D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\conf\server.xml" 
PS>$x.xml.Connector.maxConnections   
3000         
PS>$x.xml.Connector.maxThreads 
600
```

---

if you have several connectors you could do

```
$x.xml.Connector | ?{ $_.port -eq "8080"} |select maxthreads
```

Comment: thanks for your help. actually it was $x.server.service.Connector | ?{ $_.port -eq "8080" } | select maxThreads